# How to calculate a Fréchet derivative?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

What is the standard algorithm for calculating a Fréchet derivative? i.e.

$f(x,y)=x^2y$

for $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: For smooth functions $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the Fréchet derivative is just the appropriate matrix of partial derivatives. For example, the above has $Df((x,y)) = (2xy, x^2)$.

Comment: What do you mean by algorithm? To the best of my knowledge, there is no real algorithm for this, any more than there is a standard algorithm for taking the "standard" derivative.

Comment: @qaphla well, I mean something like a step-by-step solution which can be applied on a particular type of function to calculate the Fréchet derivative, hence my example

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ be (Frechet) differentiable at $x \in \mathbb R^n$.  The Frechet derivative of $f$ at $x$, which is a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$, is represented (with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$) by the matrix
\begin{equation*}
f'(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1(x)}{\partial x_n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial f_m(x)}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m(x)}{\partial x_n}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
Here $f_i$ is the $i$th component function of $f$.  In the example you gave, you can compute these partial derivatives explicitly.